# Can't convert audio files to mp3 using ffmpeg in laravel on linux server

Tags: laravel, ffmpeg, ffmpeg-php

I installed FFmpeg, php-ffmpeg, laravel-ffmpeg. Then I tried to convert Video and Audio files to mp3 on laravel.

Then it worked properly on Windows10 XAMPP.
However, when I installed the same on my linux shared server,

get error: `Class 'FFMpeg\Format\Audio\mp3' not found` and

```
A composer dependency is missing You might be missing a composer dependency. A possible package that was found is php-ffmpeg/extras.
```

So, I did `composer require php-ffmpeg/extras` and installed, however, still it produces same error.
So What would it be problem?

VoiceRecController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Post;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\support\Facades\DB;
use FFMpeg;

class VoiceRecController extends Controller
{

    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $form = Post::findOrFail($id);

        if($request->capture->extension() == 'mp4'){

            $request->capture->storeAs('public/voice/', $form->id .'.mp4');

            // Open your video file
            $video =FFMpeg::fromDisk('public')->open('/voice/'. $form->id .'.mp4');

            // Set an audio format
            $audio_format = new FFMpeg\Format\Audio\mp3();

            // Extract the audio into a new file as mp3
            $video->save($audio_format, public_path().'/storage/voice/'. $form->id .'.mp3');

            if (file_exists(public_path().'/storage/voice/'. $form->id .'.mp3')){
                \File::delete(public_path().'/storage/voice/'. $form->id .'.mp4');
            }

        }elseif($request->capture->extension() == 'mp3' || $request->capture->extension() == 'mpga'){

            $request->capture->storeAs('public/voice/', $form->id .'.mp3');

        }elseif($request->capture->extension() == 'wav'){

            $request->capture->storeAs('public/voice/', $form->id .'.wav');

            // Open your video file
            $video =FFMpeg::fromDisk('public')->open('/voice/'. $form->id .'.wav');

            // Set an audio format
            $audio_format = new FFMpeg\Format\Audio\mp3();

            // Extract the audio into a new file as mp3
            $video->save($audio_format, public_path().'/storage/voice/'. $form->id .'.mp3');

            if (file_exists(public_path().'/storage/voice/'. $form->id .'.mp3')){
                \File::delete(public_path().'/storage/voice/'. $form->id .'.wav');
            }
        }else{
        $request->capture->store('public/voice/');
        }


        return redirect('/home/mypage');
    }

}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The error you're getting is because the `Class` is called `\FFMpeg\Format\Audio\Mp3;` with a capital `M`.

Follows an example code to use it properly:

```
FFMpeg::fromDisk('public')
    ->open('song.3gp')
    ->export()
    ->toDisk('public')
    ->inFormat(new \FFMpeg\Format\Audio\Mp3)
    ->save('song_converted.mp3');
```